# From Selected DropDownList Value Remove Only The Last Comma

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am selecting values from two `DropDownList` and my condition is to remove only the last comma from the list (Getting the DropDownList into `List`). This is an old issue, I know but stuck into a simple one. This is what I've tried so far:

```
var ddlAll = new List<DropDownList>() //Lists of DropDownList
{
   ddl1, //DropDownList 1
   ddl2  //DropDownList 2
};

foreach(var item in ddlAll) //Iterating through for loop
{
   lblShow.Text += "'" + item.SelectedValue + "'" + ", ".TrimEnd(',', ' '); //Getting the values here and trying to remove the last comma
}
```

With the above code, I get the following output:

```
'Hello 2''Hello 4'
```

But my expected output is as follows:

```
'Hello 2', 'Hello 4'
```

Without the `TrimEnd()`, I get this:

```
'Hello 2', 'Hello 4',
```

N.B: There could be more `DropDownList` values but it should only remove the last comma from them.

Comment: You add a comma and then trim the end in each loop occurrence. Not just the last one.

Comment: Got it @VDWWD - Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `Trim` in every iteration. You have to change code to do it only ones, at the end. For example like this:

```
string text = "";

foreach(var item in ddlAll)
{
   text  += "'" + item.SelectedValue + "'" + ", ";
}

lblShow.Text = text.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
```

Also, I would rewrite this:

```
"'" + item.SelectedValue + "'" + ", ".TrimEnd(',', ' ');
```

using `string.Format` into:

```
string.Format("'{0}',", item.SelectedValue);
```

or even, if you are using C#6 or later, into this :

```
$"'{item.SelectedValue}',";
```

Comment: Worked perfectly @Alex - Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just use String.Join

```
String.Join(",", new List<string> { "Hello 2", "Hello 4" })
```

In your case the second parameter would be

```
ddlAll.Select(x => x.SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var item in ddlAll) //Iterating through for loop 
{ 
    if(lblShow.Text=='')
    { 
        lblShow.Text = "'" + item.SelectedValue + "'";
    } 
    else
    { 
        lblShow.Text += ", " +"'" + item.SelectedValue + "'"; 
    } 
 }
```